# How is this flex method generating a class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

So I have this code in my Flex application

```
var factory:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory( filterVOClass );
filterVO = FilterVO( factory.newInstance() );
```

At this point in the code filterVoClass is set to com.vo.ReleaseFilterVO which is a string. I know this code builds out the following object as I can Trace it in the web console.

```
 FilterVo
    Object {
        addByName: null,
        addDate: null,
        addDateRange: null,
        andFilters: null,
        artistId: 0,
        artistName: null,
        catalogNumber: null,
        changeByName: null,
        changeDate: null,
        created: null,
        depth: 2,
        duplicateUPC: null,
        exclusive: null,
        exclusiveDateRange: null,
        facets: null,
        id: 0,
        ingestionMethod: null,
        labelId: 0,
        labelManagerId: 0,
        labelManagerName: null,
        labelName: null,
        name: null,
        newReleaseDateRange: null,
        orFilters: null,
        page: 1,
        perPage: 0,
        publishDateRange: null,
        queryString: null,
        queryTermField: null,
        queryTermValue: null,
        showCounts: true,
        sort: null,
        sortField: null,
        status: null,
        supplierId: 0,
        supplierName: null,
        tier: 0,
        title: null,
        trackCount: 0,
        trackName: null,
        typeId: 0,
        upc: null,
        upcVerified: false,
        updated: null
    }
```

I just can't find that specific class anywhere in my application, and I can't find anything under the namespace to signify were these object properties are coming from.

I've read the following documentation, and I'm still not entirely sure what is happening here.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ClassFactory.html

EDIT:
ReleaseFilterVO comes from here, this is defined in a file the defined the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LookupPage xmlns="com.admin.view.page.lookup.*" 
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
xmlns:basic="com.framework.view.widget.basic.*"
xmlns:formElements="com.framework.view.form.formElements.*"
xmlns:vo1="com.framework.model.vo.*"
filterVOClass="com.vo.ReleaseFilterVO"
itemType="{ VOTypes.RELEASE }" 
label="Releases"
rowHeight="32">
```

Comment: Where does filterVOClass come from?

Comment: Edited the question to add in a reference to the data from your question.

Comment: Did you try search workspace for some property? Try search "newReleaseDateRange".

Comment: There is no defined class for which these properties exist as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an actual class reference to the factory. The factory's job is to create new instances while initializing properties with a predefined object.

```
var factory:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory( com.vo.ReleaseFilterVO );
var instance:ReleaseFilterVO = ReleaseFilterVO( factory.newInstance() );
```